# How to copy module ('com.intellij.modules.java') integrated into Intellij to other JetBrain's product?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin, fortify, java-module

After downloading and importing plugin "Fortify Analysis" to IntelliJ ewerything is working, but when I try to do the same plugin into e.g. PyCharm I see error message like that:
[image]

In [IntelliJ's documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-compatibility.html#modules-specific-to-functionality) I see that the module 'com.intellij.modules.java' is built into IntelliJ. On the other hand support from the company which is responsible for the plugin "Fortify Analysis" are telling me that their plugin should work on PyCharm (I'm using version according to [their documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2110/Fortify_Sys_Reqs_21.1.0/index.htm#SCA/IDEs.htm?TocPath=Fortify%2520Static%2520Code%2520Analyzer%2520Requirements%257C_____7)) and the problem I see is not connected with their product.

I've also tried [the solution](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-intellij/issues/446) to comment the line:

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>
```

in plugin zip file: `META-INF/plugin.xml`

I tried to find the module and copy manually but I can't find the module file after downloading [IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.2020.3.4.tag.gz](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html).

I've also tried to install every module I can find in repository `apt-cache search intellij`:

```
sudo apt-get install libintellij-core-java libgradle-plugins-java libintellij-extensions-java libintellij-platform-api-java libintellij-platform-impl-java libintellij-utils-java libtrove-intellij-java
```

But it didn't solved my problem.

**So the only solution I see is to copy the plugin from IntelliJ to PyCharm, but I don't know how to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

Bad news: I think that you misunderstood the documentation of the manufacturer of the plugin compatibility.

The [documentation you mentioned](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2110/Fortify_Sys_Reqs_21.1.0/index.htm#SCA/IDEs.htm?TocPath=Fortify%2520Static%2520Code%2520Analyzer%2520Requirements%257C_____7) lists the "Fortify **Analysis** Plugin" only compatible with Android Studio 4.x and IntelliJ IDEA 2020.x, but the "Fortify **Remediation** Plugin" in addition also compatible with PyCharm 2020.x and WebStorm 2020.x

At least your screenshot shows the "Fortify Analysis" plugin, so that's not compatible with PyCharm according to the manufacturer.